# Why are PlaylistID and Source ID changing in my iTunes database

Tags: itunes

I'm using a COM object to read an iTunes library (version 11, Windows). I call the `GetITObjectByID` function to retrieve a bunch of tracks from a list saved in a text file in a previous iTunes session.

```
GetITObjectByID(SourceID, PlaylistID, TrackID, DatabaseID)
```

I found that, occasionally, the SourceID and PlaylistID change in my iTunes database, making the function call to fail. Today, SourceID changed from 71 to 73, and PlaylistID from 63714 to 63716.  There has been no iTunes update since the IDs were saved.

Shouldn't these IDs be persistent? If they change over time, what kind of events can cause these changes?

Thanks.

PS:L In faci, I found that all IDs (SourceID, PlaylistID, TrackID, DatabaseID) were incremented by 2! Strange?